# How can I change the subtitles font size in VLC Media Player?

Tags: vlc-media-player, media-player, subtitles

That's my question: How can I change the subtitles font size in VLC Media Player? I try with Preferences > Video > Subtitles/OSD, but I can't find an option to change the font characteristics.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Linux the option is clearly visible.

[image: screenshot]

Do you have the latest version of VLC?

Comment: I've just updated my version and see that screen. Now it works, but I need to write the Font path manually, "Browse" don't keep the selection.

Comment: Changing font size in windows does not change font size

Answer (score 15):

Set "show settings" to Full, then go to Video > Subtitles/OSD > Text renderer - there you can change the font size in pixels.

Comment: Great, Accepted answer didn't work for me ( I didn't see Text Renderer ). I had to click `Show All` button to show detailed settings...

Comment: Smaller was too large for me ;)